# Inject HTML overrides in admin Template

Tags: component, administrator, template-override

I would like to create some html overrides for a given Admin Template (isis). So I could throw in all the code into the template's directory, but I guess an update will wipe out all my changes, so this might not be the best Idea. Right now I have three Ideas and I would like to ask which one to favour, or if there is any better out there:

**(I)**

The best case scenario would be to include those overrides within my component and register that location in Joomla!. Imagine the following path:

```
/admininistrator/com_somecomponent/overrides/…
```

all it contents should be treated as

```
/administrator/templates/<sometmpl>/html/…
```

But if it is possible to register that Path in the system, so that files get picked up, **how can I do that?**

**(II)**

Another way could be to copy the entire Admin Template, activate that and hack all changes in there. But than, this copied template wont get the updates of its »parent/original«, since this not a »real child theme«. **It would like to keep the updates alive, so how could that be done?**

**(III)**

Yet another way could be to create a symlink from pointing from the template to the component like so:

```
$ pwd 
$ /administrator/templates/<sometmpl>/html/
$
$ ls -la
$ com_content --> ../../../com_custom/overrides/com_content
```

This way I would have to care to create this link whenever an update occurs, what could be done within a plugin, listening to the »onExtensionAfterUpdate« Event. But It requires a lot code and I don't know how to test that, since Updates occur to rarely.

**SUMMARY**

Extending the core content type is something that really would like to do, since a long time and I am searching for a good way to do that. So if anybody has ever done that before, I would appreciate each help very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest option **1**.

Let say you want to override:

> administrator/components/com_admin/views/sysinfo/tmpl/default.php

You would simply need to copy this file over to

> administrator/templates/isis/html/com_admin/sysinfo/default.php

***Note:*** as you can see, this excludes the `tmpl` directory

You don't need to register any paths...Joomla will automatically use the override.

Comment: I would like to override component output from another component